# MSI using installshield2009

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

Is there a way to set some massage in installshield 2009 to the users to give a prompt if -

1. they rename the setup or file name is changed?
2. the setup is being run from a network location?
3. When UAC feature is turned on?

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated and welcomed.

Thanks,
Vidya

Answer (score 0):

Windows Installer provides properties to detect 1 and 2.

1. [`OriginalDatabase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370562%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property holds the path to .msi file.
   Read the notes carefully: Windows Installer renames the package when it caches the package. So your install has to cope with that.
2. [`SourceDir`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371857%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property holds the directory that contains the installation package.
   You have to schedule [`ResolveSource` action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) before using the property. And again you must be careful with that and not schedule `ResolveSource` action during uninstall for example.
3. As far as I know Windows Installer does not support direct detection whether UAC is enabled or not.

If you want to detect whether the bootstapper `setup.exe` was renamed or run from the network, that's another story and I can't help you with that.

---

Please clarify why you need to detect these two cases.

1. Why does it make difference how your setup is named?
   I don't think users rename setup files often. And if your installer package is contained in one file only, I can't see any reason why renaming is bad.

   > **Vidya:** I am not sure but users were saying that when they try to rename the setup, they are getting a message related to some compilation and setup isn’t allowing them to rename the setup.
2. What changes if the setup is run from a network location?
   Windows Installer package can be installed from a network location. In case of administrative installs, it is even a common scenario that installation is performed from a network location.

   > **Vidya:** The problem is when we install the MSI from a network location and try to run an update on the installed setup, it shows ‘File cannot be Found’
3. What do you do in the setup if you know UAC is on or off?
   Windows Installer plays nicely with UAC by itself. All you have to care about is the custom actions you write: they must be UAC-aware. This point sums to only one requirement: only deferred actions must perform modification to the system, deferred action are run in system context; other custom actions are run in the context of the currently logged in user. This requirement holds true for Windows XP as well where there's no UAC: it is a bad practice to modify system settings in a non-deferred action.

   > **Vidya:** Basically we wanted to give users a message when UAC is turned on and that user doesn’t have administrative previledges or simply informing them to either set UAC to lowest before running the setup.

Comment: Thanks for the advise Alexey. Please see my comments just below your message prefixed with Vidya

Comment: @VidyaNandTiwari 1. It depends on the setup layout. If it consists of several files, then the names of the files may be important. Is your setup in one file?

Comment: 2. It could happen that installer can't access some files over the network. In case with MSI, the installation process runs in system context: user's network drives are not mounted under system account; if network share requires user/password to access it, then system account would be unable to access supporting files on the network. Again it depends on the setup layout.

Comment: 3. If UAC is on, then all users won't have administrative privileges. To get administrative privileges, you have to elevate. In this case, if user is not a member of Administrators group, UAC will show prompt for credentials rather than simple confirmation. Turning off UAC requires reboot, anyway it's not user-friendly to require users to modify their settings for your installer to work. A good installer these days has to work correctly in UAC-enabled system as well as in system where UAC is off.

Comment: Thanks Alexey, my setup contains 4 modules (each of these module is an application in itself). For UAC features, I was reading the blogs and found that few settings inside Installshield run the setup without worrying with UAC features.

Comment: Could you please advise how can we create an MSI setup which can work without worrying on UAC enabled/disabled feature? I tried to set 'Required execution level' property to 'Invoker' but after setting this, my setup didn't do anything, it is neither being installed nor giving any error message.

Comment: You want actually `requireAdministrator` rather than `asInvoker`. It would elevate and run sub-setups in administrator context. Here by `it` I mean the first setup that users start and then I assume it executes other sub-setups.